# Android how to handle retrofit response when Content-Type = application/octet-stream?

Tags: android, retrofit

### retrofit request interface:

```
public interface IDataService {
      // Request URL:             https://demo.testdata.com/getData/order?timeStamp=1491986181670&callerId=android_platform
      // Request Method:          GET
      // Response Content-Type:   application/octet-stream
      @GET("https://demo.testdata.com/getData/" + "{type}")
      Observable<Response> getTestData(@Path(value = "type", encode = false) String type
              , @Query("callerId") String callerId, @Query("timeStamp") long timeStamp);
  }
```

### Use the retrofit request interface:

In TestActivity.java

```
public Observable<String> getTestData(IDataService dataService) {
        final BehaviorSubject<String> subject = BehaviorSubject.create();
        if (null == dataService) {
            subject.onError(new NullPointerException());
            return subject;
        }

        bindObservable(dataService.getTestData("order", "android_platform", new Date().getTime())).subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        subject.onError(e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(retrofit.client.Response response) {
                        // TODO: how to handle the response body content?
                        // In general, response is  json string. Then  parse and convert json string to Object.
                        // Now Response Content-Type = application/octet-stream, How to handle it?

                    }
                });
        return subject.asObservable();
    }
```

### Question: In general, response Content-Type=application/json, parse JSON string to Object.  Now,Response Content-Type = application/octet-stream, How to handle it?

### Ref:

- com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
- io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0
- io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0

Comment: paste your response please

Comment: Retrofit Response -> InputStream ->java bytes[] -> treat byte as short or int -> int[] or short[].

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moved solution from question to answer:

> ### Solution:
>
> I had solved the problem. The brief description for the solution is below :
>
> Retrofit Response -> InputStream ->java  bytes[] -> treat byte as short or int -> int[] or short[].
>
> ### Code
>
> Below is my detail demo code.
>
> #### Android App client, which receiver 8-bit unsigned integer array.
>
> IRetrofitService.java
>
> ```
>   public class IRetrofitService {
>     // Local Node.JS Server
>      /**
>      * FAQ: Retrofit: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
>      * Reason:Node.js server PI is http://127.0.0.1:8888/.
>      * If you are referring your localhost on your system from the Android emulator then you have to use http://10.0.2.2:8888/ .
>      Because Android emulator runs in a Virtual Machine therefore here 127.0.0.1 or localhost will be emulator's own loopback address
>      Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495534/java-net-connectexception-localhost-127-0-0-18080-connection-refused
>      */
>     private static final String PATH = "http://10.0.2.2:8888";
>     public interface ApiManagerService {        
>         @GET("/")
>         @Headers("Content-Type:application/octet-stream")
>         Observable<Response> getUnsignedBytes();
>     }
>
>    private static final RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().setEndpoint(PATH).setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).build();
>     public static final ApiManagerService apiManager = restAdapter.create(ApiManagerService.class);
> }
> ```
>
> RetrofitDemoActivity.java
>
> ```
> import android.util.Log;
> import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.hades.android.example.R;
> import com.hades.android.example.framework.BaseActivity;
>
> import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
> import java.io.IOException;
> import java.io.InputStream;
>
> import butterknife.OnClick;
> import retrofit.client.Response;
> import rx.Observable;
> import rx.Observer;
> import rx.Subscriber;
> import rx.android.schedulers.AndroidSchedulers;
> import rx.schedulers.Schedulers;
>
> /**
>  * RxJava and RxAndroid , Retrofit to request data from server.
>  * Need <uses-permission  android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
>  */
> public class RetrofitDemoActivity extends BaseActivity {
>     public static final String TAG = RetrofitDemoActivity.class.getSimpleName();
>     private int[] singedBytes;
>
>    // TODO: IRetrofitService.apiManager.getUnsignedBytes()
>     private Observable<Response> getUnsignedBytes() {
>         return IRetrofitService.apiManager.getUnsignedBytes();
>     }
>
>    @OnClick(R.id.requestUnsignedBytes)
>     public void requestUnsignedBytes() {
>         Log.d(TAG, "requestUnsignedBytes,----->");
>         bindObservable(getUnsignedBytes()).observeOn(Schedulers.io()).subscribe(new Subscriber<Response>() {
>             @Override
>             public void onCompleted() {
>
>            }
>
>            @Override
>             public void onError(Throwable e) {
>
>            }
>
>            /**
>              * Response content is 8 bites unsigned byte
>              * [246, 254, 255, 0, 10, 126, 127, 128, 129, 253, 254, 255, 0, 1, 232]
>              */
>
>           /**
>              s,buf_size=15,read_buf_size=15
>              start parse
>
>             origin = -10, afterTransValue = 246
>              origin = -2, afterTransValue = 254
>              origin = -1, afterTransValue = 255
>              origin = 0, afterTransValue = 0
>              origin = 10, afterTransValue = 10
>              origin = 126, afterTransValue = 126
>              origin = 127, afterTransValue = 127
>              origin = -128, afterTransValue = 128
>              origin = -127, afterTransValue = 129
>              origin = -3, afterTransValue = 253
>              origin = -2, afterTransValue = 254
>              origin = -1, afterTransValue = 255
>              origin = 0, afterTransValue = 0
>              origin = 1, afterTransValue = 1
>              origin = -24, afterTransValue = 232
>
>             end parse
>              */
>             @Override
>             public void onNext(Response response) {
>                 InputStream inputStream = null;
>                 BufferedInputStream bufferedInputStream = null;
>                 try {
>                     inputStream = response.getBody().in();
>                     bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(inputStream);
>
>                    int buf_size = inputStream.available();
>                     byte[] bytes = new byte[buf_size];
>                     int read_buf_size = bufferedInputStream.read(bytes, 0, buf_size);
>                     Log.d(TAG, "requestUnsignedBytes,buf_size=" + buf_size + ",read_buf_size=" + read_buf_size);
>                     if (null == bytes) {
>                         return;
>                     }
>
>                    if (null != singedBytes) {
>                         singedBytes = null;
>                     }
>                     singedBytes = new int[buf_size];
>
>                    Log.d(TAG, "requestUnsignedBytes, start parse");
>                     for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
>                         /**
>                          * First, read as the 8 bites signed byte.
>                          * Second, get the signed tag as the value.
>                          */
>                         byte origin = bytes[i];
>                         int afterTransValue = 0xFF & origin;
>                         Log.d(TAG, "requestUnsignedBytes,origin = " + bytes[i] + ", afterTransValue = " + afterTransValue);
>                         singedBytes[i] = afterTransValue;
>                     }
>                     Log.d(TAG, "requestUnsignedBytes, end parse");
>
>                } catch (IOException e) {
>                     e.printStackTrace();
>                 } finally {
>
>                }
>             }
>         });
>     }
>   }
> ```
>
> #### Node.JS is as demo server,which reponse 8-bit unsigned integer array.
>
> server.js
>
> ```
> var http = require('http');
>
> var server = http.createServer(function (request, response) {
>     var sampleBytes = new Uint8Array(15);
>     sampleBytes[0] = -10;
>     sampleBytes[1] = -2;
>     sampleBytes[2] = -1;
>     sampleBytes[3] = 0;
>     sampleBytes[4] = 10;
>     sampleBytes[5] = 126;
>     sampleBytes[6] = 127;
>     sampleBytes[7] = 128;
>     sampleBytes[8] = 129;
>     sampleBytes[9] = 253;
>     sampleBytes[10] = 254;
>     sampleBytes[11] = 255;
>     sampleBytes[12] = 256;
>     sampleBytes[13] = 257;
>     sampleBytes[14] = 1000;
>
>    console.log(sampleBytes);
>
>    var buffer = new Buffer(sampleBytes);
>
>    response.writeHead(200,{'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'*','Access-Control-Allow-Method':'GET,POST','Content-Type':'application/octet-stream'});
>
>    response.write(buffer);
>    response.end();
>
> });
>
> server.listen(8888,"localhost",function(){
>    console.log("start monitor...");
> });
>
> console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8888/');
> ```
>
> ### Ref:
>
> - com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0
> - io.reactivex:rxjava:1.1.0
> - io.reactivex:rxandroid:1.1.0