# JsonObject GET requesting from localhost

Tags: android, rest, web-services, request, android-volley

i try to call a restful webservice from à java application using Android client but every time i  have the same result "some error occurend".
i think that the problem is in my URL because i don't have any idea about calling restful webservice in Android from Tomcat and what URL i use.
this is my java Main_Activity:

```
package com.halgo.restclientandroid;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText editText;
    TextView text;
    Button btn;
    String url ="http://localhost:8080/Stage_BGI/rest/missions/find/";
    String data = "";
    RequestQueue requestQueue;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        editText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText);
        text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn);
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String urlJSON=url + editText.getText().toString();
        btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                JsonObjectRequest obreq = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url + editText.getText().toString(), null,
                        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                               /*try {
                                   JSONObject obj = response.getJSONObject("missionObject");
                                    String idMission = obj.getString("idMission");
                                    String etatMission = obj.getString("etatMission");
                                    data += "id_mission: " + idMission +
                                            "etat_mission : " + etatMission;
                                   text.setText(data);
                                }catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }*/
                                text.setText(response.toString());
                            }
                        },
                        new Response.ErrorListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                                text.setText("Some error occurred!!");
                            }
                        }
                );
                requestQueue.add(obreq);


            }
        });
    }
}
```

and this is the mainActivity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.halgo.restclientandroid.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:text=""/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/fetch"
        android:id="@+id/btn"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:text=""/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i found answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495534/java-net-connectexception-localhost-127-0-0-18080-connection-refused

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of the final `/` in your url.

Also in `onError` you can call `error.getMessage()`

Comment: about the / i make it because i will add parameters from my EditText :url + editText.getText().toString().

Comment: about the / i make it because i will add parameters from my EditText :url + editText.getText().toString().

Comment: when i use my ip address i have this Exception: java.net.ConnectException:failed to connect to 192.168.1.4(port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED(Connection refused)
when i use 127.0.0.1 i have this Exception: java.net.ConnectException:failed to connect to localhost/127.0.0.1(port 80) after 2500ms: isConnected failed: ECONNREFUSED(Connection refused)

Comment: Go to the ip in your browser.

Comment: thanks for your help, i found answer here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495534/java-net-connectexception-localhost-127-0-0-18080-connection-refused