# React Native STOMP over websocket

Tags: android, react-native, websocket, stomp, sockjs

I'm trying to build a React Native messaging app throught websocket and STOMP protocol (For the server side I'm using Spring Boot) but I get a really weird behaviour. My code is the following:

```
...
import SockJS from 'sockjs-client'; // Note this line
import Stomp from 'stompjs';

function ChatScreen() {
   // Variables declaration

   useEffect(() => {
    const socket = new SockJS('http://localhost:8080/chat');
    const stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
    const headers = {Authorization: `Bearer ${jwt}`};

    stompClient.connect(headers, () => {
      stompClient.subscribe(
        `/user/${user.username}/queue/messages`, console.log, headers,
      );
    });

    return () => stompClient && stompClient.disconnect();
  }, [jwt, user.username]);

  ...
}
```

When the above component is mounted I get:

> Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/chat

Then if I change the SockJS import line from `import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';` to `import SockJS from 'sockjs-client/dist/sockjs';` without reloading with double "r", but letting hot reloading do its job, I successfully obtain a connection to the websocket and everything works fine. Now, if I reload with double "r" and navigate to ChatScreen component again, I still get the message:

> Whoops! Lost connection to http://localhost:8080/chat

Switching back to `import SockJS from 'sockjs-client';` from `import SockJS from 'sockjs-client/dist/sockjs';` I successfully obtain a new working connection but double "r" breaks it down again.

I tested the code on both an emulator (Android 9) and a physical device (Android 10). I've also tested react-stomp and the result is the same.

For a better understanding on what I mean this is a video that reports the behaviour:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IVpiJjHsBGkhB38IWoPujI5eXPuBDbf1

I appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Hello, which stompjs do you use? I could not find `Stomp.over(a: SockJS)` from this [npm library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/stompjs).

Comment: Hi, I'm using the library you linked. You can find the method here (line 479):
https://github.com/jmesnil/stomp-websocket/blob/master/lib/stomp.js

Answer (score 2):

```
import SockJS from "sockjs-client";
import Stomp from "webstomp-client";
var connected =false;
var socket ='';
var stompClient = '';
const  send = ()=> {
      let send_message = 'hello !';
      if (stompClient && stompClient.connected) {
        const msg = { name: send_message };
        stompClient.send("/app/hello", JSON.stringify(msg), {});
      }
    }
    const connect =()=> {
      socket = new SockJS("http://uat.wealthbrain.com:7777/gs-guide-websocket");
      stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
      stompClient.connect(
        {},
        frame => {
          connected = true;
          stompClient.subscribe("/topic/greetings", tick => {
          });
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error);
          connected = false;
        }
      );
    }
    const disconnect =()=> {
      if (stompClient) {
        stompClient.disconnect();
      }
      connected = false;
    }
    const tickleConnection =()=> {
      connected ? disconnect() : connect();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution, since I'm on Android emulator I cannot use `http://localhost:8080/chat` to connect to the websocket, I have to use `http://10.0.2.2:8080/chat` instead. More details here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495789/9121838