# Android - Can I change 10.0.2.2 to localhost?

Tags: android

My test server is iis express, so I can access only localhost:port.

But android emulator's localhost hostname is 10.0.2.2, it occur Bad Request error.

I want change 10.0.2.2 hostname to localhost.

Is it possible? How Can I change it?

Comment: Your question looks like an [X-Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: `But android emulator's localhost hostname is 10.0.2.2,` No. Not at all. Localhost is localhost and localhost is 127.0.0.1. The 10.0.2.2 has nothing to do with localhost. It is used for connecting to a server that runs on the pc where your emulator is running on too.

Comment: `test server is iis express, so I can access only localhost:port.` Sorry, cannot believe that. That would be a useless test server then.

Answer (score 0):

Android emulator runs in a Virtual Machine and using `10.0.2.2` or `127.0.0.1` or `localhost` will point to the  emulator's own loopback address.

Therefore ***localhost*** will not work as a base URL - instead of changing the name you could upgrade to the Url to `http://10.0.2.2:8080`.

For more info on this you can have a look at this [Medium Post](https://medium.com/livefront/how-to-connect-your-android-emulator-to-a-local-web-service-47c380bff350). There is also [this question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5495534/java-net-connectexception-localhost-127-0-0-18080-connection-refused) which also addresses the same issue.

Comment: Please review your first sentence. You suggest that 10.0.2.2 points to a loopback address.