# How send request from react native to local server

Tags: reactjs, react-native, android-emulator

I am using android emulator and when i send request to localhost it gives me error. I have tried the forwarding the port also ngrok but none of them worked for me. It always gives me error.
`[Error:Network Error].`

Comment: consider removing flutter tag while it is not releated to this

Answer (score 0):

IN Emulator go to setting->click on Network and Internet ->then select Internet->select available network and then re-run your project and check it will work

Answer (score 0):

Please try **http://10.0.2.2:8080** instead of **localhost:8080**.
 If you are referring your localhost on your system from the Android emulator then you have to use http://10.0.2.2:8080/ Because Android emulator runs in a Virtual Machine therefore here 127.0.0.1 or localhost will be emulator's own loopback address.
[Original Answer Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5495789/14032118)