# Create SDDL failed, Error: 1332

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-express

I'm trying to use IIS Express with Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx). When I run this command.

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://Melnibone:443/ user=everyone
```

I get this message:

```
Create SDDL failed, Error: 1332
```

**What's happening?**

Comment: Is there a way to be more generic by using SID instead.

Comment: @VansFannel : Try with sddl option: "netsh http add urlacl url=https://+:443/ user=everyone sddl=D:(A;;GX;;;IU)"

Answer (score 224, accepted):

Well, I have found the problem.

I'm running Windows 7 in Spanish, so the right command is:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=https://Melnibone:443/ user=todos
```

Funny, isn't it?

**UPDATE**:

If you want, you can add a comment to this question telling us how it is in your language.

Comment: Thanks! This have haunted me for some time. My local installation is in Swedish so the user parameter should be: "user=alla".

Comment: Wow, that was interesting. I had it originally in spanish with a language pack, but I didn't see that coming :)

Comment: I have my windows in english and I am getting the same error.

Comment: And for french windows users use this: user="Tout le monde"

Comment: In portuguese is also user=todos

Comment: in Dutch it's user=iedereen

Comment: in Polish: user=Wszyscy

Comment: In spanish is also "user=todos" (as in portuguese).

Comment: Just had this issue - in my case, it was that I got the case of the username wrong, using DOMAIN\Username rather than DOMAIN\username.

Comment: in Swedish: user=alla

Comment: in Finnish: user=kaikki

Comment: in Norwegian: user=alle

Comment: Quick way to just make this work without knowing much else is to set the domain to Everyone and Host to '+': netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8282/ user=Everyone listen=yes

Comment: To get the "everyone" equivalent in the System locale: `wmic sysaccount where "SID='S-1-1-0'" get name`. *Je vous en prie* ;)

Comment: in Russian: `user=Все`

Comment: in German: user=Jeder

Answer (score 9):

For me, this issue was caused because there was already an HTTP reservation for the address and port I was using when tried to add an HTTPS reservation.

I found out what was going on when I ran `NETSH HTTP SHOW URLACL` and saw that the address was already reserved with a different protocol.

Answer (score 5):

I recently ran into this issue.  The solution for me was to run the command prompt as an administrator.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add that it might be the installation language.
I had to use the german word "jeder" though my system language was english.

Answer (score 0):

I know this question was asked a long time ago, but as there is no general answer yet, so i thought i'll share my approach. There's an easy way to filter for this with a few batch commands.

```
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in (
   'wmic sysaccount where "SID='S-1-1-0'" get name'
) do set "sid=%%a"&goto next
:next
```

The loop is necessary because the "get name" part gives the whole table with the heading so we filter for the second line. This code then stores the value of the SID according to your locale in the "sid" variable, so you only have to refer to this when you want to use it.

In this case the whole code would look like this:

```
for /f "skip=1delims=" %%a in (
   'wmic sysaccount where "SID='S-1-1-0'" get name'
) do set "sid=%%a"&goto next
:next
netsh http add urlacl url=https://Melnibone:443/ user=%sid%
```

**NOTE:** How you filter for the second line is up to you, the real "magic" happens in this line:

```
wmic sysaccount where "SID='S-1-1-0'" get name
```