# Why ASP.net page is not accessible from another machine in LAN?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, localhost

I made simple ASP.Net website, which is running well on localhost. But when I try to access it using IP address and port it not accessable and gives error,

> HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid.

URL using on localhost, (adding space in url due to some problem facing in SO)

> http ://localhost:53039/MyPage.aspx

Url using as IP address,

http: //192.168.220.156:53039/MyPage.aspx

Regards

Comment: Check this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831097/bad-request-invalid-hostname-iis7

Comment: Can be: 1. Firewall on server 2.Not define the correct name on IIS binding 3. The network not let the two machines to communicate. 4.Firewall on client, 5. from the message, probably you have not define the correct name on dns, or the name is not correct resolved (I bealive that you not use the localhost as name)