# Bad Request - Invalid Hostname on IIS8 - RestFul WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, rest, iis-8

When I try to access my RestFul WCF service on port 10374, from an external IP address I get this error: "Bad Request - Invalid Hostname" / "HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."

I'm not able to access the wcf resources also after doing some troubleshooting as described in this solution: [Bad Request - Invalid Hostname IIS7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831097/bad-request-invalid-hostname-iis7),

I made all the possible changes but I can just access correctly my service only when accessing it from the local machine: `"http://localhost:10374/"`... Anyone knows how to resolve this issue?

Comment: what address are you typing into your browser when accessing from an external machine? what bindings do you have for your site in IIS ?

Comment: The binding ip address is: 192.168.1.254:10374 (putting also an inbound "allow filter" at the firewall for the port.) The localhost binding was another test that worked only locally.